# Android Library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-library

Is there a way to keep the Android repository private and share it's dependency like normal implementation `'com.lib.converter:repo:1.0.0'`. Also without granting user any special permission?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove unused permissions, add this to your manifest:

```
<manifest ... xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.[PERMISSION_NAME]" tools:node="remove"/>
    ...
</manifest>
```